# preg_replace syntax to replace image src hostname with new hostname

Tags: php, regex, domdocument, regex-group

I need to preg_replace syntax to find and replace the img src host name from xyz.com to abc.host.prov.com
Baisically my img html tag looks like this,

```
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-27283 size-large" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-1024x1024.jpeg" alt="homemade chocolate recipe" width="640" height="640" srcset="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-1024x1024.jpeg 1024w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-300x300.jpeg 300w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-768x768.jpeg 768w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-696x696.jpeg 696w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-1068x1068.jpeg 1068w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-420x420.jpeg 420w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-560x560.jpeg 560w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3.jpeg 1080w" sizes="(max-width: 640px) 100vw, 640px" />
```

and it has to be replaced with this

```
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-27283 size-large" src="http://abc.host.prov.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-1024x1024.jpeg" alt="homemade chocolate recipe" width="640" height="640" srcset="http://abc.host.prov.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-1024x1024.jpeg 1024w, http://abc.host.prov.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-300x300.jpeg 300w, http://abc.host.prov.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-768x768.jpeg 768w, http://abc.host.prov.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-696x696.jpeg 696w, http://abc.host.prov.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-1068x1068.jpeg 1068w, http://abc.host.prov.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-420x420.jpeg 420w, http://abc.host.prov.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-560x560.jpeg 560w, http://abc.host.prov.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3.jpeg 1080w" sizes="(max-width: 640px) 100vw, 640px" />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should use `DOM` for parsing `HTML` **instead of** `Regex`, For parsing a string you can use `Regex`

**Solution 1:**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string ='
<html>
    <body>
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-27283 size-large" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-1024x1024.jpeg" alt="homemade chocolate recipe" width="640" height="640" srcset="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-1024x1024.jpeg 1024w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-300x300.jpeg 300w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-768x768.jpeg 768w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-696x696.jpeg 696w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-1068x1068.jpeg 1068w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-420x420.jpeg 420w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-560x560.jpeg 560w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3.jpeg 1080w" sizes="(max-width: 640px) 100vw, 640px" />
    </body>
</html>';

$domObject= new DOMDocument();
$domObject->loadHTML($string);
$results=$domObject->getElementsByTagName("img");
foreach($results as $result)
{
    $value=$result->getAttribute("src");
    $value=preg_replace("/^\s*(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.com/","$1abc.host.prov.com", $value);
    $result->setAttribute("src",$value);
}
print_r($domObject->saveHTML());
```

**Solution 2:** 
[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/785244)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string ='
<html>
    <body>
        <img class="aligncenter wp-image-27283 size-large" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-1024x1024.jpeg" alt="homemade chocolate recipe" width="640" height="640" srcset="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-1024x1024.jpeg 1024w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-300x300.jpeg 300w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-768x768.jpeg 768w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-696x696.jpeg 696w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-1068x1068.jpeg 1068w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-420x420.jpeg 420w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3-560x560.jpeg 560w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/image-3.jpeg 1080w" sizes="(max-width: 640px) 100vw, 640px" />
    </body>
</html>';
$domObject= new DOMDocument();
$domObject->loadHTML($string);
$domXpath= new DOMXPath($domObject);
$results=$domXpath->query("//img");
foreach($results as $result)
{
    $value=$result->getAttribute("src");
    $value=preg_replace("/^\s*(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.com/","$1abc.host.prov.com", $value);
    $result->setAttribute("src",$value);
}
print_r($domObject->saveHTML());
```

Comment: Yes, but in this case you don't really need to use XPath since `$results = $domObject->getElementsByTagName("img");` produces the same DOMNodeList. However with XPath, you can directly target the src attribute: `$results = $domXpath->query("//img/@src");`

Comment: I think this is wrong `$results = $domObject->getElementsByTagName("src");` it should be `$results = $domObject->getElementsByTagName("img");` @CasimiretHippolyte yes you are right we can use it that way also

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks friend i have updated my post... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
https?:\/\/\Kexample\.com
```

And replace by this:

```
abc.host.prov.com
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SxHX23/1/)

Sample Code:

```
$re = '/https?:\/\/\Kexample\.com/';
$str='YOUR INPUT STRING GOES HERE';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```